# Injecting a script to page with callback

Tags: javascript, dynamic-script-loading

I'm trying to inject yepnope.js to page and then loading other JS files with yepnope.

Chrome Dev Tools' network tab shows yepnope is fetched, elements tab show element is injected. But console tab shows:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: yepnope is not defined
```

Here is my code:

```
var betaApp = {


    injectYepnope: function(url) {
        var gp = document.createElement( 'script' );
        gp.type = 'text/javascript';
        gp.async = true;
        gp.src = url;

        gp.onload = betaApp.yepnopeLoaded;
        // Only for IE 6 and 7
        gp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if( this.readyState == 'complete' )
            {
                betaApp.yepnopeLoaded();
            }
        }

        document.body.appendChild(gp);
    },

    yepnopeLoaded: function() {
        yepnope([
            {
                load: ['//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js', 'http://raw.github.com/andris9/jStorage/master/jstorage.js'],
                complete: function() {
                    betaApp.firstPartLoaded();
                }
            },
            {
                load: [
                    'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js',
                    'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js',
                    'https://raw.github.com/Automattic/Iris/master/dist/iris.js',
                    'https://raw.github.com/cnkt/eksi-beta/master/ui/js/twitter-bootstrap/js/bootstrap-modal.js',
                    'https://raw.github.com/Automattic/Iris/master/src/iris.min.css'
                ],
                complete: function() {
                    betaApp.allJsLoaded();
                }
            }
        ]);
    }
};

betaApp.injectYepnope('https://raw.github.com/cnkt/eksi-beta/master/ui/js/yepnope.js');
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your code itself is fine, but you need to make sure it is called after the DOM is ready, as otherwise it can't append scripts to the document.

Either use a libraries onReady event (such as `JQuery.ready()`) - your only option if this code *must* be in a external file, or just add the script direct to your HTML at the end of the document.

Comment: i copy-pasted your code to a newly created JS file (mean: empty) and it gives me: "Uncaught ReferenceError: yepnope is not defined "

Comment: Your issue there is that the DOM is not ready when the script loads (JS is blocking remember) so document does not exist for your script to append scripts to - if you add that script directly to an HTML document (not in an external file) it should work, even better wait to initialise until after DOM ready

Comment: But dev tools' Elements tab is showing that the "script" tag is appened to "body" element.

Comment: Have you tried putting all your code direct in the HTML/ calling on dom ready? Bet you a beer it works :-)

Comment: It's a UserScript for a page. I cant modify the HTML before this script is loaded.

Comment: Probably worth adding that explicitly to your question as it makes quite a difference...

Comment: So I took another look at this, refactoring your code to use a function rather than a plain object to provide a closure, can you take at this and tell me if it works in your context? 
https://gist.github.com/3844644 - NB obviously you will need to wait to do typeof(yepnope) until the yepnope request has completed.

Comment: yepnopeLoaded functions runs but "Uncaught ReferenceError: yepnope is not defined" error comes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17642/discussion-between-meta-and-cnkt)